# zIndex not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu and a slideshow, the zindex of the menu is greater than that of the slideshow but for some reason it is being covered up by the slideshow. I looked at the documentation on zindex and cant find any reason why this is happening.

You can go to the site here: http://cp31.stablehost.com/~edenvill/

Please look at the site using chrome.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Z-index only works on positioned elements other than the default static, ie., absolute & relative.

Comment: Please do not just post a link; include the relevant code.  These questions must remain useful to future readers and for obvious reasons yours would not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you see is because the top table has the z-index set:

```
 table.top-table {
   ....
      z-index: 9 !important;
 }
```

Since the parent element in this case has a lower z-index set then children elements with higher z-index won't affect siblings to the parent. (is this understandable?)

If you increase this above 999 (the slideshow caption panel) then it will work:

```
table.top-table {

   z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```